# How to use NFC?

Tags: drivers, nfc

I have a Sony VAIO laptop installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1, And my laptop has NFC device built in. I would like to use it in ubuntu too.

**So here is my question:** Is  there any drivers for NFC in ubuntu available? or is there anything else I can do to use the NFC feature in my laptop with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that there are libraries and tools available to use NFC:

neard - Near Field Communication daemon
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/neard.8.html

nfctool - a NFC toolbox
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nfctool.1.html

Some "Libre" tools are available as well.
http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

You might start here:
https://www.google.com/search?q=NFC+in+ubuntu

Comment: Doesn't look like `neard` or `nfctool` are available anymore (Ubuntu 22). I get these errors when trying to install them via apt:

`E: Unable to locate package nfctool` 

`E: Package 'neard' has no installation candidate`